# Is it better to use public void or public [name of page] for methods in page object class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am following the page object model. Let's say I have a NewPage class that extends the BasePage and in the class I have methods like so:

```
public NewPage clickRed(){
    driver.findElement(element1).click();
    return this;
}

public NewPage clickBlue(){
    driver.findElement(element2).click();
    return this;
}

public OtherPage goToNextPage(){
    this.clickRed();
    this.clickBlue();
    super.clickNextButton();
    return new OtherPage(driver);
}
```

}

Is that okay, or for clickRed() and clickBlue() methods is it better practice to have these methods down as public void? Like so:

```
public void clickRed(){
    driver.findElement(element1).click();
}
```

Comment: It is not a big deal I think both are OK, but I'd prefer to use first approach because sometimes it is more convenient to write something like: newPage.clickRed().clickBlue()...

Comment: Oh, chaining right? That's good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you would like to achieve.

I like the fluent style. So, each method in the login page object returns 'this'.

```
loginPage.enteringUsername("uname")
         .enteringPassword("pwd")
         .submit();
```

If you do not prefer that, you can keep them 'void'

---

But why do you find element using `driver.findElement` every time in your page object?

Check this design. http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/

Comment: Thanks, I will look into page fragments, have not heard of it before!